# SQL insertar mas de un registro en una tabla en un INSERT

Tags: c#, base-de-datos, sql

quisiera hacer un query en donde inserto un registro que esta relacionada con 2 tablas mas.

**MaximosyMinimos**

```
INSERT INTO MaximosYMinimos
(ProductoID, SucursalID, Max, Min) 
VALUES
((select p.ID from Productos as p where p.ID = 1325 ), (select s.ID from Sucursales as s where s.ID = 1), 0, 0)
```

pero quiero ingresar todos los registro de la tabla de productos solamente la ID, de igualmanere para Sucursales.
Tomando las N registros de las 2 tablas anteriores, e ingresarlas a la tabla de maximos.

MaximosyMinimos

```
ID | IProductoID | SucursalID | Max | Min

1    102           20            0    0
2    103           20            0    0
3    105           20            0    0
4    106           20            .    .
5    102           21
6    103           21
7    104           21
8    105           21
9    102           22
10   103           22
11   104           22
```

Donde el ID **20** es por ejemplo, sucursal1 y **21** sucursal2 y asi susecesivamente.
Gracias.

Comment: ¿Cómo se relaciona la tabla de productos con la de sucursales? ¿Los valores Max y Min son siempre cero?

Comment: @MarcosCrispino la **tabla se llama MaximosYMinimos**, y si, los campos Max y Min, van en 0, por ahora.

Comment: Esa es la tabla donde quieres insertar los registros. Yo me refiero a de dónde salen los datos, qué relación hay entre las tablas `Productos` y `Sucursales`.

Comment: @MarcosCrispino los datos (En este caso solo la ID) los tomaria desde productos y sucursales, todos los registros para ingresarlo en esa tabla, es una tabla podria decirse que es un indicador para determinar los maximos y minimos que contiene cada producto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres hacer es el producto cartesiano de las tablas `Productos` y `Sucursales`, e insertarlos en una tabla junto con el valor `0` para los campos `Max` y `Min`, entonces la consulta es la siguiente:

```
insert into MaximosYMinimos (ProductoID, SucursalID, Max, Min)
select p.ID, s.ID, 0, 0 from Productos as p, Sucursales as s
```

Comment: gracias. me ayudo tu respuesta